# passing file path as command line parameter in python

Tags: python

I need to write something into files, which I am passing through command line in python. I am using the below code `mycode.py`

```
import csv
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
row = ['4', ' Danny', ' New York']

with open(r"path" , 'w') as csvFile:
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
writer.writerow(row)
```

When I execute it, the file is not written, but when I hardcode path as

```
 with open(r"C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\python\sam.csv", 'w') as 
 csvFile:
```

the file is being written, Please let me know if I am missing anything.

One more requirement is I have to pass only the directory in open, and append some file name.
For example: I can pass

> C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\python, sam.csv

I have to append to the directory in code.

Comment: You're passing "path" as a string literal and not as a variable. Try replacing 'r"path"' with just 'path' (without quotes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `path` variable's value.

Replace

```
with open(r"path" , 'w') as csvFile:
```

with

```
with open(path , 'w') as csvFile:
          ^^^^
```

If you want to *append* one file to a *directory* path, you could use `os` package.

```
file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
```

Comment: well that worked, how can i append file name to path, 
for example: my path variable be C:\Users\venkat\Desktop\python, i should append sam.csv as file to path.

Comment: You could use `os` package. `os.path.join(path, file)`

Comment: os.path.join(path, "file_name") , file name as string creates a file under my path directory, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Well this worked

```
import csv
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
row = ['4', ' Danny', ' New York']

with open(path, 'w') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append(or write) an existing file,this worked too using `format`:

```
path="insert\\pathOf\\file.txt"
with open("{}".format(path),'a') as file:
    file.write("excellent\n")
```

The 'a' is for append,so it will add the 'excellent' string to file.txt.
If you want to write a new file just put 'w' instead of 'a'.

Using 'w' will overwrite  the file.txt if already exists.
The \n is for ending in new line so if you run the same code 2 times it will add 'excellent' in two different lines and not side by side.

Answer (score -1):

You should add curly braces if you want to convert it to raw format

```
with open(rf"{path}" , 'w') as csvFile:
```