# Trying to call a file path from the command line

Tags: python

I am trying to call a file path from a Windows machine and use it to open a CSV file. The code looks like the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 26 18:56:53 2019

@author: stacey
"""
import os
import argparse
import pandas as pd
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
def main():

    #run check_file_data.py -p 'C:\Users\simon\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv'
    #path for the csv file
    path = r'C:\Users\stacey\Downloads\PythonTest\InterestRate_history_raw.csv'    
    path = get_args()
    path = 'r'+path

    check_file_data(path)

def check_file_data(path):

    data = open_csv(path)


def open_csv(path):    
   rawData = pd.read_csv(path) 
   return rawData

def get_args():

        path =''

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Path to run check file')
        parser.add_argument('-p', '--path', type=str,help='path of the file that you want to check for outliers ,stale and missing data ',required = True)
        args = parser.parse_args()

        ''' Assign args to variables'''

        path = args.path
        return path


if __name__ == "__main__":


    try:

        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```

where I am using the command line argument

```
run check_file_data.py -p 'C:\Users\stacey\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv'
```

to run the code.

However I am getting the following error:

```
run check_file_data.py -p 'C:\Users\simon\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv'
path
rr'C:\Users\simon\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\simon\Downloads\check_file_data.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()

  File "C:\Users\simon\Downloads\check_file_data.py", line 25, in main
    check_file_data(path)

  File "C:\Users\simon\Downloads\check_file_data.py", line 30, in check_file_data
    data = open_csv(path)

  File "C:\Users\simon\Downloads\check_file_data.py", line 84, in open_csv
    rawData = pd.read_csv(path)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 373, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:4184)

  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 667, in pandas.parser.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\parser.c:8449)

FileNotFoundError: File b"r'C:\\Users\\simon\\Downloads\\PythonTest\\Equity_history_raw.csv'" does not exist
```

The path does exist (I have run the code previously with the path hard coded successfully).

What do I need to do to get the path to be accepted?

Comment: No need of `'r'+path`. You can pass it directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing file path as command line parameter in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295670/passing-file-path-as-command-line-parameter-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding "r" character to the path (path = 'r'+path) and that is why it doesn't exist.

```
b"r'C:\\Users\\simon\\Downloads\\PythonTest\\Equity_history_raw.csv'"
```

The `r'` is a part of the path and you don't want that.

Comment: thanks, removing the r from the path has unfortunately no effect (still get error FileNotFoundError: File b"'C:\\Users\\simon\\Downloads\\PythonTest\\Equity_history_raw.csv'" does not exist

Comment: You still have the leading and trailing `'` in your path. Maybe run just: run check_file_data.py -p C:\Users\simon\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv

Answer (score 0):

Just remove r from string below

```
path = 'r'+path
```

Or

```
currentDir = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(currentDir, path)
```

And you can check your path exist below:

```
os.path.exists(path)
```

Comment: I think you need to join paths by using os.path

Answer (score -1):

As an option, you can use `pathlib` for convert passing string arg to a path object for check if path is existing.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 26 18:56:53 2019

@author: stacey
"""
import os
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std

def main():

    # run check_file_data.py -p 'C:\Users\simon\Downloads\PythonTest\Equity_history_raw.csv'
    # path for the csv file
    path = r'C:\Users\stacey\Downloads\PythonTest\InterestRate_history_raw.csv'
    path = get_args()
    # path = 'r'+path
    if path:
        check_file_data(path)

def check_file_data(path):
    data = open_csv(path)


def open_csv(path):    
   rawData = pd.read_csv(path) 
   return rawData

def get_args(): #  Union[Path, str]

    path = ''

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Path to run check file'
    )

    parser.add_argument( 
        '-p', 
        '--path',
        type=str, 
        help='path of the file that you want to check for outliers ,stale and missing data ', 
        required = True
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    ''' Assign args to variables'''

    path = Path(args.path)
    assert path.exists()
    return path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("Ctrl+C pressed. Stopping...")
```